# Problem when I try to install ubuntu

Tags: partitioning

When I try to install Ubuntu I got this error:

```
The ext4 file system creation in partition #1 of SCSI3 (0,0,0) (sda) failed
```

I boot from USB. Can anyone tell me how to fix this? :D

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot from a live CD.  When presented with the desktop, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the commands below:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

When the installation is done, just type:

```
sudo gparted
```

And Delete the Ubuntu install partition, and then restart the installation.

Comment: Does not work :(

Comment: Well, Can you at least run Gparted?  If yes, can you upload an image somewhere, and I'll add it for you?

Comment: Yes i can run Gparted but i don't know what to do.

Comment: Once you run it, just do a print screen, save the image and upload.

Comment: Photo: http://i43.tinypic.com/4t1vzp.png 

Yea i know, that's backtrack..

Comment: Well go ahead and delete `/dev/sda2`and `/dev/sda5`, and then restart the installation.

Comment: Ok, i tried and the error is keep showing...What should i do ? :|

Answer (score 0):

That error often results from a hardware fault on your hard disk. I recommend you run a SMART test. In Linux, tools like the text-mode `smartctl` and the GUI GSmartControl can do this; or most disk manufacturers have tools to do these tests from Windows, if you've got a Windows installation on another disk. The SMART test will tell you if your disk is failing, although the results can be difficult to interpret, so you may need to ask for help. If the disk is going bad, replace it; *DO NOT* install to a disk that fails its SMART test!